# Hive Time stamp conversion issue

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera

I am using my cloudera Hive 0.14 . I am not able to typecast for different dates please help

Below functions works fine

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180104060037','yyyymmddHHmmss'));
```

Output:

2018-01-04 06:00:37

But when I use below function with change in month it is not getting changed please help

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180204060037','yyyymmddHHmmss'));
```

Output:

2018-01-04 06:00:37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue, here you used the `yyyymmddHHmmss` but for month you have to use `MM` `(yyyyMMddHHmmss)`. Now try this

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20180204060037','yyyyMMddHHmmss'));

2018-02-04 06:00:37
```